# Zend Framework IBM DB2 Connection Script application.ini

Tags: zend-framework, db2

This is the script I'm trying to convert in to a standard application.ini zend_db connection:

```
require_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Db2.php'; 

$config = array( 'dbname' => '*LOCAL',
                 'username' => '', 
                 'password' => '', 
                 'os'=>'i5', 
                 'driver_options'=> array("i5_commit" =>DB2_I5_TXN_READ_UNCOMMITTED,
                                          "autocommit"=>DB2_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF, 
                                          "i5_lib"=>'WEBLIB'));
```

I don't know how to address the driver_options in the application.ini dot syntax. If it was just a regular connection string, I wouldn't have difficulty.

I would appreciate any help or direction.

Answer (score 0):

i use this application.ini config:

```
resources.db.adapter = "Db2"
resources.db.params.dbname = "*LOCAL"
resources.db.params.ip = "192.168.1.100"
resources.db.params.os = "i5"
resources.db.params.persistent = true
resources.db.params.driver_options.autocommit = DB2_AUTOCOMMIT_ON
resources.db.params.driver_options.i5_naming = DB2_I5_NAMING_ON
resources.db.params.driver_options.i5_libl = "WEBLIB"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

Comment: This is wonderful!  Thank you! I am going to try this right away and I will certainly let you know how it turns out.